# Customize Dropdown Menu, when to trigger hide menu event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I created a dropdown with ul and li tags, the thing is I am not sure what is the best time to hide the dropdown menu.

I made the dropdown menu will display the values based on what user is inputting when user is typing, and update the menu dynamically. I was having the hide menu event on the input box's onBlur event, in this way I can see the dropdown menu, once I click on a menu item, the blur event will be triggered and the menu will be hided, the value will be filled into the input box with js code. But, if the menu is long, and it has a scroll bar on it, when I click on the scroll bar, the blur event will be triggered too. I was trying to add some check, if currently I am focusing on the scroll bar, but that seems not possible, when I click on the scroll bar, the focused element is the DOM body.... Can anyone think of something, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

my sugestion is to run 0.0 -0.5 timeout on blur of input event,just make sure to save timeout id so you can clear it on mouseenter to menu,

Comment: For some other reasons I do have 0.5 second timeout on the blur event, forgive me, I don't quite understand this "just make sure to save timeout id so you can clear it on mouseenter to menu" Could you please give me more details, thank you.

Comment: @TechNoob all SetTimeout return int timeoutID; if you safe it to global variable you can call window.clearTimeout(timeoutID); and it will prevent function from being called.

Comment: but, when should I call window.clearTimeout, I can't find any proper event I can use when I click on the scroll bar...